# Snookered by abstract - PHP

Tags: php

I have an abstract class I am inheriting from:

```
abstract class Test
{
    public function GetTests()
    {
    }
}
```

and I have a concrete that I have been using the abstract classes implementation for most of the time:

```
class Concrete extends Test
{
    // No problemmos
}
```

I recently had to implement a different version of the GetTests method, and in fact I wanted to overwrite it as it's built into all of my routing:

```
class Concrete extends Test
{
    public function GetTests( $newArgument )
    {
        // notice $newArgument
    }
}
```

However I get this error message:

```
Declaration of Concrete::GetTests() should be compatible with Test::GetTests()
```

Apart from copying the entirety of the functions from the abstract class for this concrete, even though I only need to implement this one method differently... Is there a way of getting around this?

I do understand that I could have:

```
abstract class Test
{
    abstract public function GetTests();
}
```

But this is why I am snookered, because I no longer have the ability to modify how the underlying Test class is implemented... doh!... Unless I really have to..

---

**Thanks to all great answers...**

I have decided to de snooker myself (it's going to hurt but it's going to be worth it) and I will instantiate the Test class inside the Concrete class, implement concrete versions of all the Test class methods, and then inside them just call the instantiated Test class... This means in the future (or indeed now) I can simply not call that feature...

For context:

```
/* no longer abstract */ class UnitOfWorkController
{
    public function GetUnits()
    {
        // Implementation
        return View::make(...);
    }
}
```

and...

```
class SomethingController /* no longer extends the UnitOfWorkController */
{
    private $unitOfWorkController;
    public function __Construct()
    {
        $this->unitOfWorkController = new UnitOfWorkController();
    }

    public function GetUnits()
    {
        return $this->unitOfWorkController->GetUnits();
        // or I could just implement my own junk
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not compatible because of the `$newArgument`. You can either add this parameter to the abstract, or remove it from the `Concrete` class ; but indeed, it has to be compatible

Comment: Just to see if I understood properly: you wish to be able to override the abstract class function right ? If I understood correctly you have to make your `$newArgument` optionnal (from [this doc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php)) depending on which version of php, not declaring it and trying to get it with `func_get_args` maybe ? (really unsure on this last point)

Comment: I don't know who to mark as answer, but I have put my solution into the end of OP, please give me feedback on it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your concrete subclass is in violation of the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), which to cut a long story short says that if an object of class X can be processed by a given piece of code, then every possible subclass of X must also be able to be processed by the same piece of code.

Say I wanted to make another subclass of Test and wanted to implement my own GetTests method.  The base class method doesn't accept any arguments at all, so that suggests that, if my subclass is to be substitutable for its superclass, my implementation of that method cannot take any arguments either.  If I give my implementation arguments, then it no longer conforms to the specification as laid down by the superclass.

If I have code that does:

```
$object = new Test;
$test -> GetTests ();
```

then I can't substitute my subclass of Test without also changing the calling code to pass in an argument.  Likewise if I do change it, then I have another subclass of Test that doesn't require an argument for GetTests then the code would have to change again.  In fact the same code simply can't be used as is with both subclasses without having to jump through some hoops to determine the actual class and using the appropriate calling convention which means needing to know things about the class I'm about to use that I shouldn't need to know.

PHP is less strict than most OO languages about subclass method signitures matching their superclass, but it will issue a warning if they don't match.  The only way to fix the warning is to have all subclasses have the same method signatures as the superclass they inherit from.

Answer (score 1):

Child methods must have the same signature as the same method in a parent class. This includes required parameters and their typecasting.

For example, a child class of the following method must also have one parameter, and the parameter must cast to the `ArgumentType` class or a child of thereof.

```
public function something(ArgumentType $Argument)
{
}
```

You can, however, make the parameter *optional* by setting it to `null` or any other value:

```
public function something(ArgumentType $Argument = null)
{
}
```

In this case, child methods may omit this parameter.

From the PHP docs, see http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php:

> […] Furthermore the signatures of the methods must match, i.e. the type hints and the number of required arguments must be the same. For example, if the child class defines an optional argument, where the abstract method's signature does not, there is no conflict in the signature.

Answer (score 1):

The method signature of `Concrete::GetTests()` has a variable while  `Test::GetTests()` does not.  Since  you have already defined this method within `Test`, it is now being inherited.  The inherited version is not compatible with your overridden version.

Here are your options:

1. Add `$newArgument` to the parameters list in `Test::GetTests()`.
2. Remove `$newArgument` from the parameters list in `Concrete::GetTests()`.
3. Rename `Concrete::GetTests()` to something else.

Answer (score 1):

PHP does not support this, as the error message says. If you want to override the function, it has to have the same footprint, which in your case it doesn't

What you could do is use a magic method: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call

the parameter array is a separate entity, so you 'decide' in your code (which you can override) what to do with which parameter.

I wanted to link a blog I read about this, but couldn't find the one I was thinking of. There is [this rather strangely formatted one](http://www.techflirt.com/tutorials/oop-in-php/overloading-and-overriding.html), not sure if it any good, but it does touch on some of the issues.

You could obviously add the argument to the parent, but this is 'leaking' upwards. If other childeren want even more, you'd get a big party of random paramteres that all can be nulled.