# PHP > 5.4: overriding constructor with different signature

Tags: php, oop, constructor

We know that PHP doesn't accept child methods with a [different signature than the parent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26259387/3908235). I thought that was the same with constructors: The PHP documentation [states](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php) that

> This also applies to constructors as of PHP 5.4. Before 5.4 constructor signatures could differ.

However, it appears that inherited constructors *still* can differ in PHP versions > 5.4. For example the following code does not trigger any warnings or notices:

```
class Something { }
class SomeOtherThing { }

class Foo
{
    public function __construct(Something $foo)
    {
    }

    public function yay()
    {
        echo 'yay';
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo
{
    public function __construct($foo, SomeOtherThing $bar = null)
    {
    }
}

$x = new Bar(new Something());
$x->yay();
```

According to the documentation, the code should trigger an error, as the contructor signatures are different.

Tried this on PHP 5.6.4. Same effect with [other versions](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/37e5c924cfb64b5a0cff9abf040c90a344c68b46).

So, what's up with that? Are differing constructor signatures still legal, despite of what the documentation says? Or is this a bug which will be fixed in later versions?

Comment: This is related to __abstract__ methods, not concrete implementations

Comment: @zerkms - it's a mechanic that allows you to define a signature, in exactly the same way an interface would define a signature `abstract public function __construct(Something $foo);` That signature is then enforced in classes that extend the abstract..... it may not be a sensible practise to do so, but that's what the docs page that OP has linked to is talking about

Comment: @MarkBaker and it's a nonsense: constructor **IS NOT** a part of interface and it must not be polymorphic. Constraining a constructor arguments is silly. I hardly believe php team made that available.

Comment: @zerkms, php has never been marked as a perfect language. It has its flaws (actually quite many).

Comment: @zerkms: I agree, but why does the PHP documentation state that inherited constructors must not differ from the parent? That's the real question here.

Comment: @lxg php dev team for some reason added it, but the feature itself is silly and must not be used.

Comment: Btw, my post is not an invitation for PHP bashing. The question is no *how it should be, according to OOP theory*, but whether or not this is intentional behaviour in current versions of PHP.

Comment: Who says that the feature “must not be used”? There are use cases where it makes sense, especially when *extending* the list of accepted constructor parameters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php)

> Unlike with other methods, PHP will not generate an E_STRICT level error message when __construct() is overridden with different parameters than the parent __construct() method has.

So, that is why you are not getting an error of level E_STRICT. Perhaps it will trigger something at a different level.

Comment: Well, not really satisfying either, but at least it appears to be documented/intended behaviour. Btw, as I mentioned, it doesn't even trigger `E_NOTICE` or `E_STRICT`.

Comment: Note, the docs say abstract class signatures must match. The classes provided in the question are not abstract classes.

Answer (score 3):

I think you somewhat misread the documentation, because it states:

> Furthermore the signatures of the methods must match, i.e. the type
>   hints and the number of required arguments must be the same. For
>   example, if the child class defines an optional argument, where the
>   abstract method's signature does not, there is no conflict in the
>   signature.

You've defined an optional parameter, so it's ok.

Comment: No. The first parameter demands an instance of `Something` in the parent class, while there's no such requirement in the child class.  If this was a normal method and not a constructor, it would cause errors: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f6c69deb75feb14184a150ac9ac83cded9c747aa

Comment: And, btw, if the second parameter wasn't optional in my example, it would still work: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/256a056c0297315527004d6f6310daf53ef5bf42